# Issue with the DispatchQueue not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, combine

I am stuck with this issue and tried various ways but no luck. Below code used to work few days back. However, its not working now. I tried with the Xcode version 11.1 and works like charm. Can someone let me know what could be the reason or a workaround?

Issue is whenever I typed in a key, it does not fire the corresponding method using the dispatchqueue.

Current Swift version: 11.3

```
Code snippet:

 init(
    weatherFetcher: WeatherFetchable,
    scheduler: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "WeatherViewModel")
  ) {
    self.weatherFetcher = weatherFetcher
    _ = $city
      .dropFirst(1)
      .debounce(for: .seconds(0.5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
      .sink(receiveValue: fetchWeather(forCity:))
  }
```

Reference code:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/4161005-mvvm-with-combine-tutorial-for-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial has a problem, which is that the subscriber created by the chain `$city.…` isn't saved anywhere, so it is immediately cancelled and deallocated. Either save it in a property or add it to a `Set<AnyCancellable>` property using  `.store(in: &mySubscribers)`.